# Flutter iOS Build Error Multiple Commands product Runner.app/Runner

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

Trying to get the iOS side of my flutter app up and running.  Ive got quite a few plugins, have gone thru and added all the dependencies in the info.plist file and set up everything.  But I cant seem to get it working.  Ive found answers for the multiple frameworks but it doesnt fix this issue.  Heres the output:

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/user169291/StudioProjects/scryer/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/user169291/StudioProjects/scryer/ios/Runner/Runner' to '/Users/user169291/StudioProjects/scryer/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner'
    2) Target 'Runner' has link command with output '/Users/user169291/StudioProjects/scryer/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner'

    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/user169291/StudioProjects/scryer/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner' on task: Ld /Users/user169291/StudioProjects/scryer/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner normal x86_64 (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
```

Im at a lost and been looking for a solution for a couple days now.  This is the last thing holding up my app release

Comment: So did you ever fix it?? If so, plz share in an answer! Some of us are still lost, here... 